# Tk Tablelist, How to disable interactive editing using left mouse button

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

By default Tk tablelist starts editing when I click on editable cell by left mouse button. I want the cell to be editable but I want to edit it in other way, not by pressing left mouse button. I want to use left mouse button click for something other. How can I make tablelist not to start interactive cell editing when I click on left mouse button.

Comment: Don't know enough to answer, but the answer is going to be in the bindings…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. I used `return -code break` in left mouse button click handler. You can read about it here http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm.